# Typescript compiler work but Javascript result is wrong

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, express, compiler-warnings

First of all, I want to show you my directory tree:

```
\__ root
     \__ node_modules
     \__src
          \__ dir1
               \__ index.ts
               \__ package.json
               \__ deploy.config //not important here

          \__ dir2 //architecture like dir1
          \__ dir3
          \__ ...

     \__ package.json
     \__ //some configuration files
```

I have tried to add types on my NodeJS project by adding Typescript. For that, I have installed many things into the **root** folder:

1. npm i -D typescript
2. npm i -D @types/node
3. npm i -D @types/express

See there the **index.ts** script into the **dir1** folder:

```
'use strict'

const toolPath = process.env.TOOLPATH || '';

import express, { Response, Request } from 'express';

var app = express();

app.get('/test', async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
    res.send("Hello world !");
});

module.exports = {
    app
};
```

To test typescript compiler I used the following command in **dir1** folder: `npx tsc index.ts` and see the result below:

```
index.ts(9,28): error TS1005: ',' expected.
index.ts(9,42): error TS1005: ',' expected.
index.ts(9,54): error TS1005: ',' expected.
index.ts(10,8): error TS1005: ':' expected.
index.ts(10,30): error TS1005: ',' expected.
```

I do not know why I have some errors into the index.ts in

An **index.js** file was created but it contains errors:

```
'use strict';
var toolPath = process.env.TOOLPATH || '';
var express_1 = require('express');
var app = express_1["default"]();
app.get('/test', async(req, express_1.Request, res, express_1.Response), {
    res: .send("Hello world !")     //<--- ERROR THERE
});
module.exports = {
    app: app
};
```

Actually, I do not know why the compiler does not work but I am sure that is not a big mistake. I know that I can use a **tsconfig.json** file but I want to keep the actual project architecture.

Furthermore, I want to extract the **index.js** file into the current folder (if the script was launched into the **dir1** I want to compile into **dir1** folder).

I want to put a script in each **package.json** in each **src** folder to compile it and then deploy my directory into the cloud.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this:

1. `npm i -D typescript`
2. `npm i -D @types/node`
3. `npm i -D @types/express`

You have installed only types for node and express.

Fix by installing these dependencies, just like you have installed the typescript ;)